# How do you turn on device speakers for Android using adb shell

Tags: android, adb

Have not seen any commands regarding turning the Android device speakers on using "adb shell", curious if there is a way?

```
#call phone
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:X-XXX-XXXX

# ******* put speaker on here *******

sleep X

#end call
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
```

Answer (score 0):

To [set Speakerphone on](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)) from `adb shell` use:

- in Android 4.4.4: `adb shell service call audio 35 i32 1`
- in Android 5.1.0: `adb shell service call audio 36 i32 1`
- in Android 6.0.1: `adb shell service call audio 30 i32 1`
- in Android 7.0+: `adb shell service call audio 29 i32 1`

Replace `1` with `0` to set it off.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am rooted and when I enter in the command, the output I get:
Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')

It does not seem to be working? Should the button get "selected" when that command is entered?

Comment: UI does not get updated. What's your android version?