# Turn on device speakers via adb in Android 11

Tags: android, adb, speakerphone

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924801/how-do-you-turn-on-device-speakers-for-android-using-adb-shell) while trying to figure out the adb command for my Pixel 5 running Android 11.

When I run the suggested command for Adroid 7.0+ - `adb shell service call audio 29 i32 1`, it turns mute on and off and not the speaker.

I'm wondering if there is an updated spec, I just can't seem to find it.